# Name error when calculating the average error between two data sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to calculate the average error between two data sets and write the result to a file but my code gives this error:

> NameError: name 'first1' is not defined

Could you please tell me how to fix this error?

The command I use to run the code is here:

> python script.py input1.txt input2.txt > output.txt

**My code:**

```
import numpy
from numpy import *
import scipy
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from pylab import *
import scipy.integrate
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
import sys

def main(argv):
    t = open(sys.argv[1])
    first1 = t.readline()

    tt = open(argv[2])
    second2 = tt.readline()
    return [first1], [second2]

def analysis(first1, second2):

    first = np.array(first1, dtype = np.float64)
    second = np.array(second2, dtype = np.float64)

    #Average error
    avgerr = (first - second).mean()

    return [avgerr]

analysis(first1, second2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

**input1.txt:**

```
2.5
2.8
3.9
4.2
5.8
```

**input2.txt:**

```
0.8
2.5
3.2
5.8
6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you stuck on this?  The first active statement executed in your main program is

```
analysis(first1, second2)
```

Neither of those variables is defined anywhere in the main program.
That's why you get the error.  The sequence you have is something like this:

```
import stuff
define (but don't execute) main function
define (but don't execute) analysis function
call analysis, giving it variables first1 & second2
```

Again, those variables are *not* defined yet.

Comment: I don't how to fix it, because I don't know what you're doing.  Are those supposed to be the names of the files from the command line?  The data in the files?  Something else?

Comment: I assumed that picking up command-line arguments could *not* be your problem, considering the many examples and tutorials on that topic.

Comment: Great; then the on-line sources for working with `args` (try `kwargs` if you need to refine the search`) should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
analysis(first1, second2)
```

Is causing the error. This is because you are calling the function without providing values.
The way you have structured your code is it's expected to be run via command line.

If you want to test your script without using command line, you could change your code line above to..

```
analysis('input1.txt', 'input2.txt')
```